# How to pass data from relations before creating form?

Tags: forms, symfony

Here is my part of my form where i'm creating a new student:

```
  $students = new students;

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($students)
    ->add('name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Imię','attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))
    ->add('grupa_id', ChoiceType::class,array('choices' => $id), array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class,array('label' => 'Dodaj ucznia', 'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))
    ->getForm();
```

I have relations between students Entity and Grupa Entity.

When I'm adding new student I want to choice him only to one group. So I need to create ChoiceType field and pass there id of groups. But I don't know how to do that. Like above it doesn't work of course.

I show them later like that:

```
 $studentsList = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:students')->findBy(array('grupa_id' => $id));
             $Grupa = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Grupa')->Find($id);
```

grupa_id is FK in students Entity.

I don't know what else I should tell about my problem. If you can help me and need some more information just ask me.

Thanks for help

[image]

Comment: If you have a doctrine relation between students and grupa, then in your form it should be an EntityType instead of ChoiceType. You will find many articles for EntityType here.

Comment: I change it on '->add('grupa_id', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'AppBundle:students', 'label' => 'grupa_id')...'

Comment: And added  'public function __toString() {
    return $this->name;
    }'                    but it works with string values. I need to put there grupa_id.   When i'm trying to insert record via database it show me great. I need this same in code.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html) can help you?

Answer (score 0):

As @Rawburner said you should use [EntityType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) and then if you want more control on your field (EntityType) **grupa_id** use [choice_name](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-name) and [choice_value](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-value) overriden options.

Another thing, if you want to pass date before creating the form you can use FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA events. Now these solutions will depend on what you actually want to do.